# Where does Storybrooke get all of their stuff?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

Aside from a short stint, Storybrooke is protected from the outside world so that it cannot be found, meaning that items cannot be shipped in from outside sources.

But we often see Storybrooke residents making reference to items that they could not produce themselves, or have on hand. For example, the mechanic talks about waiting for parts, and the Dwarves complain about their DVRs, DVDs, etc.. Granny is constantly making food that no one seems to be growing themselves.

**Do all of these items just magically get created and show up in shops?**

(Possibly backing up this idea is the fact that there seems to be no employee/workers who know how to fix the power plant.)

Comment: Can we do the blanket statement of: Magic?

Comment: It's shipped in by the Black White And Green Smoke shipping company.

Answer (score 4):

There appears to have been a flaw in the original curse cast by Regina. In some flashbacks we see that right upon their arrival a few "strangers" wander into Storybrooke. These strangers are Kirk and Owen. Regina is also able to contact an adoption agency to adopt Henry, as well as contact them again to track down his mother. When Emma moves in, movers bring her stuff from her old place to her new place.

Because only the residents are stuck in Storybrooke, Regina or others could be ordering food and other resources into town. Everything from the internet, to cable would all require outside interaction, so either it is all apart of the magic of Storybrooke, or there is contact with the outside world via phone/letter bringing stuff into Storybrooke.

Answer (score 0):

The curse prevents the town from being seen by unintended visitors. People who are meant to enter can.

The reason Kurt and owen were inside the town was because they were already there inside the curse perimeter when the curse was cast. Owen returned later after the curse was lifted.

Comment: "The curse prevents the town from being seen by unintended visitors. People who are meant to enter can." is there a quote or concrete example of this you can show?

Comment: The evidence is right in the question itself.

Comment: @Escoce I'm confused by your comment. I see no evidence in the question. Please elaborate.